# Open-source IntelliJ IDEA plugin to support Mathematica development

Tags: development

Although we already had a question asking for [development alternatives to Wolfram Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5184/187), I want to ask a more specific question:

> One of the most advanced IDE's especially for Java programming is [IntelliJIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which is as well available as [open-source community edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html). Is it possible to use this highly advanced environment to develop *Mathematica* packages like in Wolfram Workbench?

### Details

The people using *Mathematica* and developing packages can be divided in two types. The first type uses the front end exclusively even to write packages. The second type uses for package writing either Wolfram Workbench or a normal editor. The Workbench has several advantages

- it has highlighting and advanced *Mathematica* editing capabilities
- it supports the creating of documentation for packages which can be opened in the Documentation Center
- it supports debugging, testing and profiling of packages
- it has the support of advanced features like other IDE's, e.g. VCS support, support of Java, ...

On the other hand, there are disadvantages and the biggest one is, that the Workbench is closed source but still has many missing features and bugs. Therefore, the developers (like me and you) can do nothing but accept the situation although there surely are people who would help to improve the program and fix bugs.

One viable solution is to start building an open-source alternative to Workbench. One might ask why not building a plugin for Eclipse because Workbench *is* basically just an Eclipse with extended functionality. The reason is simple: I have experience with both Eclipse and IDEA and I think IDEA outperforms Eclipse in usability and functionality. Furthermore, I'm already a bit familiar with the plugin structure. Therefore, for a fresh start I would go for IntelliJIDEA.

Comment: There's an "answer your own question" checkbox ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I need one or two days more to bring everything in shape but I wanted to throw out the question some time before.

Comment: So you're giving us one or two days to try to catch up with you? :)

Comment: @Szabolcs I give you some time to refresh your java knowledge and start the engines.

Comment: @halirutan If I had two days of free time, I'd perhaps join the fun :-)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I bet you could give him a run for his money in those two days time ...

Comment: I could at least give it a try, but mostly just for my own sake, since I could learn a lot in a short time (having this motivation). I doubt I would actually be able to produce anything close to what @halirutan has in just two days.

Comment: There's a problem with using IntelliJIDEA on Mac OS X: it requires Java 6. However, the current version of Java is 8. My understanding is that it's impossible for two different version of Java to coexist under current versions of OS X.

Comment: @murray I'm using it without problems under the latest Yosemite. What exactly is the problem? Do you refer to *using* the plugin or *developing* the plugin? AFAIK all IDEA plugins must be compiled with Java 1.6

Comment: @halirutan: When I start IntelliJ IDEA, I get a pop-up saying, "To open 'IntelliJ IDA' you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime." But as I understand things, if you have Java 7 or 8 JRE installed, then you cannot also have Java 6 JRE: Yosemite (and possibly Mavericks, too) allows only a single JRE to be installed.

Comment: @murray I checked the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and I found two versions 1.6.0_37 and 1.7.0_45. My OS X version is 10.10.3 and everything works fine. My IDEA uses the 1.6 version

Comment: @halirutan: in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` I find only `jdk1.8.0_31.jdk`. From https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#restore : "Can I restore Apple Java 6 after uninstalling Oracle Java 7?
Yes, see the instructions on the Apple website Restore Apple Java 6. If you have JDK 7 or later versions installed on your system and you want to restore Apple Java 6, then those JDK versions need to be uninstalled first. See the instructions to Uninstall JDK."

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is a constantly growing answer. To make it easier to track the updates of this answer, I separate every added section and give appropriate headings. If you read this for the first time, please start directly below. Updates to this answer can be found at the end.

Most important thing first: There is an

- [Official website for the plugin](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/)

and here is a quick *howto install*

- Download the **free** [Community Edition of IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)
- start it and go to *Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories*
- Search for "Mathematica" and install the **Mathematica Support** plugin: Right click (on OSX <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseClick</kbd>) on *Mathematica Support* and *Install Plugin*.
- After a restart everything is set up and you can create a *File* -> *New Project* where you find now a *Mathematica* section.

---

(Original answer)

### Yes, we can...

...extend IntelliJIDEA and make it a smart IDE for *Mathematica* package development. I started to develop such a [plugin for IDEA](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin) a while ago and before going into the details, let me show you how it looks.

[image]

What you see above is the IDE with an opened *Mathematica* package. The code is highlighted and fully parsed, therefore when you made any syntactical errors, the green point at the upper right corner wouldn't be green. The parser gives you helpful messages when you made an error and shows you the point where it recognises that something is wrong. Furthermore, you see the documentation popup showing you on-the-fly help for built-in functions and operators. Let's look at some specific things in detail.

### Autocompletion

Currently the plugin autocompletes built-in functions while you are typing. You can use of course the famous [Camel hump completion](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker), meaning you don't have to type all the sub-words to a function: to get a completion for `AlgebraicIntegerQ` you can just have to type the sub-word starts `AlInQ`. Here is an example

[image]

The first choice is always selected automatically, so you can accept it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or (if you want to insert brackets for functions automatically) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Usually, there is no need to trigger the completion manually, but you can always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to do so. Using the arrow keys you can navigate through the list of suggestions and note, that you can call the *QuickDocumentation* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> even inside this completion list.

### Quick usage lookup of functions and operators

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (OSX <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>) when you are over or beside a function or operator opens instantly a popup window showing you the usage, options and attributes of it. For instance in this example while being over `Message`

[image]

This even works for all (but the most trivial) operators. With this, you never have to remember whether to use `@@` or `@@@`.

[image]

### Matching braces, brackets and parenthesis

IDEA always tries to keep your braces correct. This means, if required it inserts matching braces and even if you close already closed braces, it tries to make intelligent decisions. Furthermore, matching braces are highlighted when you navigate through the code.

## Further development

Everything related to the development of the plugin will be announced and documented in the [Wiki of the GitHub repository](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/wiki). First of all, I have to test parser and fix some minor bugs before continuing. Although I have a detailed list of features which you find in the [README.md](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin), I invite everyone to edit the [Wish List](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/wiki/Wish-List) in the Wiki.
If someone thinks he/she can contribute to the Java-code itself, feel free ping me in the [chat room for the plugin dev](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica).

## Important links

- [BugTracker where you can report any issue/bug](http://halirutan.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issues/MMAP).
- [GitHub repository for the plugin](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin)
- [Development Wiki page where I will add helpful information](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/wiki)
- [The Plugin in the official Jetbrains Plugin Repo](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=7232). This is the Due to the really easy update process, you can find the most recent version there.

---

### Update (5. October 2013)

A lot of bugfixes, mostly under the hood, were done but additionally, some fancy features were added too. Here are the most important

**Smart completion of `Options`**

Smart option completion gives you only the options which are valid in the function you are currently in. Therefore, if you are in a position where you want to add an option to a function, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows (or completes) only options which are possible at this place:

[image]

**Completion of function arguments or local `Module`/`Block`/`Table`/.. variables**

IDEA is now fully aware of all the local variables you have defined. Therefore, it will suggest them for you while you are typing (or when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> explicitely). Note that, of course, *Camel Humps* are working there too. This lets you use verbose variable names and it pushes your programming speed off limits.

[image]

**Renaming, resolving and showing usages of local variables**

IDEA lets you now easily see where you defined and used a symbol. Additionally, renaming of all instances is done in one step:

[image]

### Update: Formatting engine working (14.11.2013)

Although not perfect, I want to make an unofficial release which includes the *Formatting engine*. If you want to try it, please deinstall your current plugin first, download the [plugin zip file from here](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/tree/feat_formatter) and install it with Preferences -> Plugins -> Install From Disk.

The core part is the *reformat code* functionality which can be triggered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on OSX) or the line-wise *auto-indent* code which can be triggered by using <kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image: Formatter]

In addition to this, I had to improve the *smart enter* which helps you to complete a statement and can be triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Therefore, try writing

```
Module[{blub},|]
```

with the cursor at `|` and the press smart enter. You see that it automatically puts the braces down and indents your cursor. Or type

```
Module[{var},
  var = 1;
  var+=v|
]
```

end when the autocompletion for `var` pops up, press smart enter. You see that it not only completes the variable name, it additionally reformats the line, puts a semicolon at the end and goes one line below

[image]

And before I forget, we have now our own *Code Style* settings section when you go to Preferences -> Code Style

[image]

There you can adjust which operators should be surrounded by space and you can define the indent. Wrapping and Blank Lines is not working right now.

Comment: wow, its fast. I'll have to play with it some more.

Comment: can you run mma code in it, or is it just an editor, at the moment?

Comment: @rcollyer At the moment it is nothing more than an editor. But even now you can create *Mathematica SDKs* by giving the path of a M-installation. This finds beside all AddOn packages the `JLink.jar` which we will use to support communication/evaluation with M. I have to say, this is currently not top of the TODO list.

Comment: @halirutan How can we make you change it to a top priority ? You are developing a (great) IDE after all.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I guess one way would be to become an expert at java and pitch in, so that halirutan is not overwhelmed by the task at hand :)

Comment: Noob question: how exactly one creaste Mathematika SDK from a path of an M-Installation?

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy Currently, there is no need to do this because the SDK (although it extracts all the package paths etc) is not used. If you still want to do this, then you have to do it *after* you created a project. There is still a bug preventing that you can create the SDK in the *new project* dialog. Therefore, *after* you have your project you go to *Project structure* (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) -> SDKs and you create a new Mathematica SDK selecting the path to your installation.

Comment: @halirutan: So far so good, thanks! Now, how can I run the code? it looks like the Run is disabled :S

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy Please look at the second and third comment :-)

Comment: @halirutan: My bad. In any case, your addon saved a lot of sanity for me, mainly though sane undo and coloring/formatting.

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy I'm always unsure of how many people use the plugin and whether they know of the [bugtracker](http://halirutan.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issues/MMAP) and other resources. If you find bugs or other issues or have feature requests, just make a login and create a new issue.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks! It's fixed now.

Comment: @halirutan Can Mathematica call the formatting function of this IDE?

Comment: Even if it could, it would currently make not much sense. The formatting engine of IDEA is very conservative: It doesn't insert linebreaks, it allows different formatting styles and it doesn't force the user to a specific style. Basically, the only thing I force is that linebreak inside a new `[`, `(`, or `{` forces one more indentation level, and unfinished expressions that are separated force a new *continuation indent*.  I left it that unspecific because I have seen so many different formatting styles and I didn't want the users to have to change their own styles just because of the IDE...

Comment: ..Therefore, even if you could magically call the formatting engine on Mathematica input, the linebreaks that Mathematica used wouldn't be adjusted and the code would not look better. To make this useful, you would have to force some more rules (e.g. how a `Module` or a `Block` is broken into lines) but that would definitely annoy some users. Therefore, I left it pretty unspecific. But anyway, the current answer is *no*, it is not easily possibly to call the formatting engine.

Comment: @halirutan In Workbench one can run MUnit test suits and get a nice output (Wolfram Unit Tester) showing how many tests succeeded and which tests failed. My project heavily relies on unit tests (we have almost 3K tests so far) so that a good support for MUnit or the availability of a comparable testing framework is crucial. Could you please  comment on the status of unit tests in your plugin?

Comment: @vsht [Please read here in the Plugin Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21715099#21715099)

Comment: @halirutan I see. Well, I think that "running the test-files as commandline parameter and interpreting the result in IDEA." would actually be sufficient. It is not that much work to write a custom testing framework, but usually one wants to see the colored results in the IDE and not some text somewhere in the console. Let's hope that at some point you might find enough free time and interest to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. It works great. Nonetheless, I'm having issues with folding the code. It will not recognize folding blocks of code, moreover, if you define a custom folding block, they will be forgotten after you close the file. Im using MacOS Mavericks with IDEA 14.1.3

Comment: @elbOlita I have no experience with *custom folding* but I certainly know how to implement folding support for the plugin. Throughout the whole time I was working on features, I very often tended to concentrate on things that I personally use (I know, very selfish). Code folding is one of the things I hate :-) Nevertheless, if there were more people who would love this, I probably would add it to the plugin. The implementation will be very similar to how code-indentation works.

Comment: @elbOlita I hope you have seen, that code folding is now completely supported by the latest version of the plugin :-)

Comment: @halirutan I just updated and saw it indeed. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Öskå Mind to join me in [chat]?

Comment: Noob alert: as there is no option to "run", what is the work flow process? Do you write code in intelliJ and then go to wolfram and manually compile each time to text your code?

Comment: @halirutan Please tell me how to establish the Mathematica SDK, but IntelliJ IDEA keeps prompting that the installation directory of Mathematica is "not a valid home for Mathematica SDK"

Comment: @AlexanderZeng Would you mind joining [the plugin chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica) for a second so that I can ask you about your system etc?

Answer (score 8):

Actually IntelliJ IDEA can build and run Wolfram code.

[Mathematica REPL on Github](https://github.com/unchartedworks/MathematicaREPL)

I think it's a good start. Let me explain what happened in the GIF below.

After I change the code in IntelliJ IDEA, I press Command+R, then the REPL(Mathematica) will build and run the code. I don't have to leave IntelliJ IDEA, I can code In IntelliJ on the fly and see the results in the REPL.

[image]

Comment: +1 More details please :) See additionally [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica) where I wrote a very long answer to your message in chat.

Comment: What does it mean to "build" the code?

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right, there is no actually build phase, it loads the code.