# How to use Mathematica for traditional programming

Tags: programming, core-language, meta-programming

I am new to the structure of Mathematica. I understand that in the notebooks, one enters the symbolic expressions and evaluates them. But I need to generate some simulated data and do that a few thousand times within a for loop. Now, do I create separate files like macros or functions that I call from my notebook or do I write my code directly into the notebook?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193) thread, starting from [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193) answer. It's better to understand the paradigm beforehand.

Comment: For loops see the documentation under For[], Do[], While[]. Sample data generation can be done in many ways using random numbers, see RandomReal[] and the "See also " section.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for making me aware of the paradigm. It does seem as though one can use Mathematica for the everyday practice of a mathematician. However, is there a good tutorial on writing essays etc. with Mathematica? My grand contribution to this forum will be that I will write an implementation of the Plamen & Koev algorithm for any hypergeometric function of matrix argument following their paper. @belisarius Could you direct me to a post that explains usage of a notebook as a real 'notebook'? Thanks!

Comment: @Hirek Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/5058854/353410

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Ad Hoc Programming: Notebooks**

It is very common for programming problems to be solved completely without leaving the confines of a single notebook.  A notebook can contain any combination of function definitions and expressions that use those functions.  See, for example, the [Function Definitions](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/function-definitions/) section of the [Fast Introduction For Programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/).

The nicest thing about notebooks is that they can contain any mixture of code, prose, graphics, animation, audio and other objects.  See [How to Create a Lecture Notebook](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateALectureNotebook.html) for an example.

**Library Re-use: Packages**

With increased usage, one might find some functionality has usefulness for more than one notebook.  The need arises to store such functionality in a library for reuse.  Such libraries are called "packages" in *Mathematica*.  A package can be easily referenced from within a notebook, making all of its functions available to that notebook.  See [Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html).

**Interactive Development Environments (IDEs)**

Packages can be authored directly within the *Mathematica* front-end environment.  However, many programmers prefer a more conventional IDE.  There is an open-source [Mathematica Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/142).  Alternatively, there is a commercial plug-in for Eclipse called [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/).

**Version Control**

Notebooks are convenient for improvisational programming tasks, that involve a single developer.  They are unfriendly in a collaborative environment involving source control because a notebook acts more like a binary file when it comes to merging.  The *.m* files (or, as of version 10, *.wl* files) that store packages are simple text files that version well.  The IDEs mentioned above have plug-ins to support common version control systems such as SVN or GIT.

**How To...**

The [How To](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HowToTopics.html) section of the *Mathematica* documentation is handy for new users.  For the present question, see especially the *Notebooks and Documents* section.