# Code editor automatically forcing new line unnecessarily

Tags: front-end

Sometimes, Mathematica starts a new line of code, even though there is still enough space. For example, I have:

```
  ( metricMatterODEReducedCSSNωV[[3]] = 
            FullSimplify[
Denominator[metricMatterEqnReducedCSSSolVx] V'[x] - 
 Numerator[metricMatterEqnReducedCSSSolVx]]) /. 
pp
```

where the Zoom has been set to 150%.

Lowering the Zoom makes it work of course. However, weirdly enough, removing the parentheses "()" removes this line break (I can still add quite a few more characters before it breaks (correctly this time) again). Alternatively, putting a ";" at the end also "pulls" the "pp" back to the upper line.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24556/open-source-intellij-idea-plugin-to-support-mathematica-development

Comment: Perhaps you want something like the `"Code"` style. If you set `PageWidth->Infinity` for the `"Input"` style, you do not get the line wrapping.  You have to manually hit return where you want line breaks.  You can get that functionality on a cell-by-cell basis with the menu Format > Word Wrapping > Don't Word Wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The front-end's code editor has many quirks. Line breaking is where a lot them live. On the whole I think the editor does a pretty good job, but I know a lot of people disagree with me on that.

Aa well as window's magnification, window width also affects the line breaking. I'm running V11.3 on macOS 10.13.4. I always set my front-end windows to a width of 800 pixels. So I get something different than what you show.

[image: window]

Parentheses seem to encourage the code editor to break early. Sometimes adding a space just before a forced line break will get rid of it; sometimes not. Here is an example where it happens to work:

[image: work_around]

The upper code snippet shows a line break inserted by the editor when there was still plenty of space remaining on the line. The lower code snippet shows a space inserted after the semicolon the ends the line. As you can see, doing so removed the forced linebreak.