# Is is possible to use regular expressions in the search and replace diaglog?

Tags: searching

I find myself wanting to be able to do regular expression search and replaces in the Mathematica gui over and over again.  Using a regex capable editor (such as vim), I could do something like:

```
 :,$ s/ *+ *s\>//cg
```

for a prompted search and replace of '+ s', '   +s', '+s', ..., but not '+ sa' (say).  Is there any thing that offers similar capability in the Mathematica GUI?

Comment: The Find window (Cmd/Ctrl+F) is a notebook, you might get something by exploring the functionality there: `Get[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","SystemResources","Find.nb"}]]`

Comment: Very much related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6723/1952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the WorkBench if you have some cash needing to abandon your wallet.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So, it sounds like this is effectively a 'no' then.  Sounds like I'm stuck with cut and paste into an editor, manipulate and paste back.

Comment: @PeeterJoot I can't find references denying explicitly the existence of such feature. But you know, those things are hard to find