# Revert FullForm back to "normal"

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I am trying to find the function that converts the result of FullForm back into a standard pretty looking output. Here is what I mean:

```
expr = FullForm[2 + 2 Sin[x]]

> Plus[2,Times[2,Sin[x]]]

Normal[expr]
Evaluate[expr]
DisplayForm[expr]

> Plus[2,Times[2,Sin[x]]]   (* not good, it's still displays as text *)

% 

> 2+2Sin[x]  (* good, I have a pretty formula again *)
```

Ok, so evaluating % just after does the trick, but it's not a function call.
I was wondering what is the proper function that does this:

```
ProperFunctionCall[expr]

> 2+2Sin[x]
```

The secondary question is: does `ProperFunctionCall` works on all types of inputs, for example, would it work on:

```
expr2=FullForm[Graphics[Disk[]]];
ProperFunctionCall[expr2]
```

and show the pretty black disk instead of the text ?

I had a look at the online help of all the entries of `?*Form` that seemed meaningful but it did not help me. I also had a look at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/742/revert-fullform-ed-text-to-prettyprinted) and a few others, but it does not seem to be the same problem so the answer did not help either.

Thanks.

Comment: `ProperFunctionCall = First`.

Comment: `ProperFunctionCall = # /. FullForm -> Identity &`

Comment: Related: [(3098)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/121), [(44189)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FullForm`, as well as all other `*Form` functions are wrappers which display in a special way. They are meant for display only.  Normally one never assigns them to a variable.

You should almost never need to do something like

```
expr = FullForm[2 + 2 Sin[x]]
```

This expression cannot even be computed with because `Head[expr] === FullForm`.  (Consequently, you could extract the contents with `First[expr]`.)

Instead, use

```
expr = 2 + 2 Sin[x]
```

Now you can re-use `expr` in calculations.  If you need to look at its full form, use

```
expr // FullForm
```

---

This is also discussed in point (8) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/12).  A very common mistake is to assign `matrix = MatrixForm[...]`.  But then `Head[matrix] === MatrixForm`, so it cannot be used in typical computations such as `matrix.matrix`.

Comment: Or to do both at once use parentheses: `(expr = 2 + 2 Sin[x])//FullForm`