# How to convert a tree in a list?

Tags: core-language, trees

I have a Tree representing a list, and I would like to plot this list. Unfortunately when I try to listplot my tree mathematica doesn't plot anything.

So, I would like to convert my tree into the list that this tree represents.

What is the function to do it ?

[edit]

to be more explicit here is my problem :

If I have a list, no problem I can plot it.
[image]

Now imagine that after some manipulation my list has been transformed in a tree, how to put this tree back to the original list to be able to plot it ?
[image]

As you can see in this second picture, the listplot doesn't work on this tree.

(here it is a simple example, in fact I have a code and at the end my list are trees, but i want to transform them into the list they represent but I don't know how to do it)

Comment: Probably, this may help: [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098)

Comment: Ok in fact my problem is that I have list that are always displayed as trees. I want to plot them but the listplot function understand them as trees and not as list so it doesn't plot. How to put them back to their original form as list ?

Comment: The topic you advised is closed to my problem but I did'nt found here how from a tree I can go back to a list.

Comment: Use `(a=b) //TreeForm` instead of `a=b//TreeForm`

Comment: Thank you I will try this, but in fact my problem is slightly different from what I asked at the beginning. I just have a Tree that I want to convert in the list it represents and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: "a Tree representing a list" - a concrete example would be nice.

Comment: I edited my message with pictures to be explicit :)

Comment: ...why plot `v` when you still have `u` which you can plot?

Comment: It is just a simple example, i have a more complicated code where my list are intermediatly transformed in trees. Here I could use "u" but in my code it is not that simple

Comment: `ListPlot[{v[[1]]}]` or `ListPlot @@ v`?

Comment: Why not rewrite your code so that there is a version that is not wrapped in `TreeForm[]`? `s = (* complicated expression here *); stree = TreeForm[s];`

Comment: Related: [Revert FullForm back to “normal”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146442)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
u = Range[5];
v = u // TreeForm;
```

then the original list `u` is the first (and only) argument of `TreeForm`, so

```
ListPlot[v[[1]]]
```

[image: plot]

You should always keep in mind the many of Mathematica's list manipulation functions such as `Part` and `First` (which could also be used in this case) work on expressions with any head, not just lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
u = Range[3];
v = u // TreeForm;
```

You can also use `Apply (@@)` to change the `Head` of `v`:

```
foo @@ v
```

> foo[{1, 2, 3}]

```
Sqrt @@ v
```

> {1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}

```
ListPlot @@ v
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or the change the `Head` (that is, `Part` 0) directly:

```
 v[[0]] = ListPlot; v
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]